# Simple floating point maths in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, math, floating-point, bignum

I need to do some basic floating point math stuff (adding and multiplying money) for a website UI. I know that Javascript floats aren't accurate because of how they're stored, but I also know that somehow, it's possible to get the level of accuracy I require. I know this because Google's calculator can do it (type "calculator" into the Goog)..

Anyway, I don't want to have to send my little numbers back to the server and have to wait for a response, so I'm trying to use a library called [BigNumbers.js](http://mikemcl.github.io/bignumber.js/), but I can't figure out how to make it spit out numbers (or strings) no matter what I call, it returns a BigNumber object.

Here's my test code: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w715yq1f/)

```
floats = [145, 1.44, 1.3];

sum = new BigNumber(0);

for(i=0; i<floats.length; i++){
    sum = sum.times(floats[i]);
}

// sum = sum.toDigits(); //returns object
// sum = sum.toString(); //returns 0

console.log(sum); // expecting 271.44, getting object
```

How can I achieve the expected result? If there's a better library to use, that would be an acceptable answer as well.

Thank you.

Comment: When you're working with money and something like BigNumbers, you're working with **fixed point** numbers, not floating point. (Which is the right thing to do for money.)

Comment: what about ye'olde dirty typecast? sum = sum +  " ";   it should convert it to string.

Comment: Have you tried [`toFixed()`](https://mikemcl.github.io/bignumber.js/#toFix)?  Eg `console.log( sum.toFixed(2) );`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to initialize `sum` to `1` instead of `0` (and maybe change its name to `product`), and then call `.toString()` when you pass it to `console.log()`:

```
console.log(sum.toString());
```

*edit* — also, as pointed out in a comment, you should set the number of decimal places (to 2, probably) and also set the rounding mode. You can do that via the `BigNumber.config()` call.

Comment: i cant freaking believe i've been multiplying by zero this whole time.. thanks

Comment: You need also to set number of decimal places `BigNumber.config({ DECIMAL_PLACES: 2 })`

Comment: @Adelphia I would also recommend changing your multipliers from floats to fixed point if you want the accuracy (`1.44`, `1.3` should be `new BigNumber('1.44')` and `new BigNumber('1.3')`)

Comment: @dsh Thanks, I've done that with the config method as suggested in the answer, and I now realize that all numbers have to be converted to BigNumber.

Comment: @Adelphia yes, you kind-of have to go all-in :)

Answer (score 1):

You can go just fine with the JavaScript floating values and `Math.round(..)` method used to round cents:

```js
var floats = [145, 1.44, 1.3];

sum = 1;

for (i=0; i<floats.length; i++){
  sum = Math.round(sum * floats[i] * 100)/100;
}

console.log(sum.toFixed(2)); // expecting 271.44
```

Comment: yeah, idk why i didn't just do that. obviously i didn't have my head on right this morning.

Comment: Yeah, it happens.to everyone. Good brand of coffee usually works for me :)